# PHP MySQL While loop for SELECT from two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there i am working on PHP code that is selecting columns from two tables.

Here is my code:

```
$result2  = mysql_query("SELECT  * 
                         FROM   `videos`, `m_subedvids` 
                         WHERE  `videos.approved`='yes' AND 
                                `videos.user_id`='$subedFOR' 
                         ORDER BY `videos.indexer`
                         DESC LIMIT $newVID");

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $indexer   = addslashes($row2['videos.indexer']);
    $title_seo = addslashes($row2['videos.title_seo']);
    $video_id  = addslashes($row2['videos.video_id']);
    $title     = addslashes($row2['videos.title']);
    $number_of_views = addslashes($row2['videos.number_of_views']);
    $video_length    = addslashes($row2['videos.video_length']);
}
```

When i try to print `$indexer` with `echo $indexer;` it's not giving me any results.
Where is my mistake in this code?

Comment: `videos` is your tale name... it won't be part of the column name, so it should be just `$row2['indexer']`

Comment: Add to the end of the `mysql_query` command the following: `or die();` and show us the output to know if the sql query failed.

Comment: try `var_dump($row2)`. It'll show you what you're fetching back from the database - it's not what you think it is.

Comment: Here is the whole code from the page please check it: http://pastebin.com/cFMvgY3b

Comment: it's interesting how the input has no filter, but the output has addslashes()

Comment: What do you mean how i can fix that?

Comment: @TonnyStruck  - what do you mean by it's not working? Are you not getting any results? Getting results but they're not being printed out? Have you checked to see if the query is succeeding? Is there anything in `mysql_error()`?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like the key `'indexer'` isn't in your results. It's hard to tell, since you haven't listed a definition for your table and you're using `SELECT *` so we can't see the names.

It makes the program easier to read later, if instead of `SELECT *...`, you use `SELECT  col1, col2, ...`. Yes, `SELECT *` will save you some typing right now, but you'll lose that time later when you or anyone else who works on your code has to check the table definition every time they work with that line of code.

So, try changing your query to explicitly select the columns you use. If it's an invalid column you'll get an error right away rather than this silent failure you're getting now, and you'll thank yourself later as well.

Answer (score 0):

So long as `videos.indexer` is a unique field name among all tables used in the query you can change

```
$indexer = addslashes($row2['videos.indexer']);
```

to

```
$indexer = addslashes($row2['indexer']);
```

You don't need to (or can not) use the table name when referring to the result.

Comment: And again it's not working.
Here is the whole code from the page please check it: http://pastebin.com/cFMvgY3b